# SQL server 2019 alwayson problem

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I've SQL server 2019 STD always on set up with 2 nodes and file share witness (located on third server). yesterday we had an network issue that the main switch was down for 15 minutes. after the network is back i see that the whole SQL server alwayson cluster was deleted from the computers completely. how this thing can be happened at all?

THX

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing that would cause the removal of the Availability Group resource from the cluster entirely.

There is automatic removal of replicas which can occur, but that would be just the replica and shouldn't be the entire AG resource in the cluster. Note that in Standard Edition there is only a single secondary replica allowed, so worst case is you'd still have the AG but with a single replica (potentially no replicas, but that's a SQL thing not a cluster thing).

You'll need to go over the SQL Server errorlog and Windows Server Cluster Log to get more information. It's not possible to give any further insight as no data has been provided.